# MySQL join only on row existing

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following query

```
SELECT custconcompany, custconfirstname, custconlastname, custconemail, custconphone, shipaddress1, shipaddress2, shipcity, stateabbrv, shipzip, countryname, websitecheck.formfieldfieldvalue websitevalue, excludecheck.formfieldfieldvalue excludevalue
            FROM obcisc_customers 
            JOIN ( (obcisc_shipping_addresses JOIN obcisc_countries 
                    ON obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipcountryid = obcisc_countries.countryid)
                LEFT JOIN obcisc_country_states 
                    ON obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipstateid = obcisc_country_states.stateid 
                LEFT JOIN obcisc_formfieldsessions websitecheck
                    ON obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipformsessionid = websitecheck.formfieldsessioniformsessionid 
                LEFT JOIN obcisc_formfieldsessions excludecheck
                    ON obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipformsessionid = excludecheck.formfieldsessioniformsessionid) 
ON obcisc_customers.customerid = obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipcustomerid 
            WHERE custgroupid = 11
            AND websitecheck.formfieldfieldid = 24
            AND excludecheck.formfieldfieldid = 30
            AND excludecheck.formfieldfieldvalue != 'a:1:{i:0;s:3:"Yes";}'
            ORDER BY shipstate, shipcity
```

This works great except I also need it to return rows where "excludecheck.formfieldfieldid=30"  does not exist... right now it's not returning them

Comment: `AND (excludecheck.formfieldfieldid = 30 OR excludecheck.formfieldfieldid IS NULL)`?

Comment: so first you said `WHERE ... AND excludecheck.formfieldfieldid = 30` and *This works great* and after you wan * where "excludecheck.formfieldfieldid=30" does not exist* so do you need it to be 30? or to exclude when 30?

Answer (score 0):

When writing a `LEFT JOIN`, any criteria on the table you're joining with should be put into the `ON` clause. If you put it into the `WHERE` clause, you'll filter out the results in the first table that don't have a matching row in the second table, because the `NULL` value that comes from the outer join will not match the criteria.

```
SELECT custconcompany, custconfirstname, custconlastname, custconemail, custconphone, shipaddress1, shipaddress2, shipcity, stateabbrv, shipzip, countryname, websitecheck.formfieldfieldvalue websitevalue, excludecheck.formfieldfieldvalue excludevalue
FROM obcisc_customers 
JOIN obcisc_shipping_addresses
    ON obcisc_customers.customerid = obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipcustomerid 
JOIN obcisc_countries 
    ON obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipcountryid = obcisc_countries.countryid)
LEFT JOIN obcisc_country_states 
    ON obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipstateid = obcisc_country_states.stateid 
LEFT JOIN obcisc_formfieldsessions websitecheck
    ON obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipformsessionid = websitecheck.formfieldsessioniformsessionid 
       AND websitecheck.formfieldfieldid = 24
LEFT JOIN obcisc_formfieldsessions excludecheck
    ON obcisc_shipping_addresses.shipformsessionid = excludecheck.formfieldsessioniformsessionid
       AND excludecheck.formfieldfieldid = 30
       AND excludecheck.formfieldfieldvalue != 'a:1:{i:0;s:3:"Yes";}') 
WHERE custgroupid = 11
ORDER BY shipstate, shipcity
```

Another way to do it is by putting `(excludecheck.formfieldfieldid = 30 OR excludecheck.formfieldfieldid IS NULL)` in the `WHERE` clause. But this is more verbose and also I believe it's harder for MySQL to optimize, especially if you have several tables you're joining like this.

Comment: neither of those works for what i need. the query example returns 112 rows (many duplicates)  and the OR just returns 2 results. i guess the easiest thing is to just go through and make sure all of them have a value for formfieldfieldid=30  and it fixes my problem with my query.

Comment: If you make a sqlfiddle with sample data, and show what the desired result is, maybe I can figure out what's wrong. Also, you can get rid of duplicates using `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: they arent actual duplicates. there are some addresses in obcisc_shipping_addresses that have Exclude=No  and some that have Exclude=Yes  and some that have no Exclude value... i need to return all that have Exclude=No or no value... and it was easier to just go through and make sure all have a yes or no than to figure this query out, so it's solved i guess.

Comment: Like I said before, make a sqlfiddle and update the question with the desired result.